# Paste values to a sheet in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have already created a code wherein I search for a specific word/s in a text file and store them on a variable. The process of searching for these words or string is by line on the .txt file.

Now my problem is that I don't know how to paste that string to a sheet in excel. What I want to do is that every time the code sees the word i'm looking for, it paste it to a cell in a specific worksheet, then paste the next word it finds to the cell below it, so on and so forth.

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks!

Comment: Please add more details about your problem and your own efforts this far to solve the problem so that people can help you better. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable stores strings and let's call it Variable1 for example.
Let's also assume you are storing the results in Sheet2, Column A. Would something like this help?

```
Sub test()
If Variable1 <> "" Then
   Sheet2.Activate
   Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
   ActiveCell. Value = Variable1
```

then add an Else or ElseIf to continue running your search, etc...

Comment: Great, no probs!